# Can I use the cpp MIN_VERSION conditional for a haskell package?

Tags: haskell, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I noticed that I can get backwards compatibility with base by adding a CPP conditional like so:

```
moo :: Moo
moo = Moo
    { happyMoo = Sound "moo"
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,1)
    , upgradedMoo = Sound "moo"
#endif
    , sadMoo = Sound "moo"
    }
```

But I get an error when I specify package-level dependencies (ie: using something like `#if MIN_VERSION_optparse-applicative(0,13,0)`) and I'm having a hard time finding documentation on this GHC feature.

I'm wondering if something like `MIN_VERSION_optparse-applicative` exists and, if not, how do hackage maintainers keep code backward-compatible?

Comment: `MIN_VERSION_optparse-applicative` is invalid CPP identifier. Try `MIN_VERSION_optparse_applicative`.

Comment: ahhhh, I tried that but it worked this time. It looks like I was also using four version numbers previously, where the macro must take three numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the macro documented [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) and [here](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-package.html?highlight=conditional#conditional-compilation).

The issue here is package names get mangled in such macros; in particular, dashes get replaced by underscores. So it should be e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

foo :: String
foo = 
#if MIN_VERSION_optparse_applicative(0,13,0)
  "x"
#else
  "y"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it seems like before I was using four version numbers which also broke the macro.